# Zabbix Media Type Parameters not replaced correctly

Tags: api, webhooks, zabbix, zabbix-api

I'm trying to call an API with Zabbix when there is a security warning

[image: settings]

But when I receive the warning, some elements are not replaced.

However, the HOSTID parameters seems to exist in the [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/fr/manual/api/reference/host/object)

Here is the object I receive

[image: received object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{HOST.HOSTID}` is a non-existent macro, there isn't a direct mapping from the api fields and the macros.

You should use `{HOST.ID}`

You can find the complete macro by location list [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location)